# Instagram api get all number image by tag and range date

Tags: image, api, date, instagram, hashtag

I have a problem, I would say if it is possible to get the all number image by tag and range date. 
If I use https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/sunshine I can get all number image but I don't know how I can filter this result by range date (from 1 July 2015 to 31 July 2015), I tried to use max and min timestamp but they don't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tags endpoint does not support `max_timestamp` and `min_timestamp`, so cannot filter by date range currently.